# No values in instance vars of objects after I add them to NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c

I'm adding an object w/two NSString instance vars to an NSMutableArray.  Log statements tell me the vars are set correctly, but after I add them to the array, they seem to be overwritten or later, don't show up at all.  This is driving me nuts.  I suspect its a memory mgmt issue...

Sorry for the long output, but I'm getting desperate...

I call this method when I click a button and it takes text from a textview, then I call another method from a menu item, and I have log statements to iterate through the array to check the values of the instance vars (question, answer) and both are blank in each Flashcard object saved in the array...

```
- (IBAction)nextCard:(id)sender
{
    int i = 0;
    NSLog(@"> Clicked \"Next Card\" button");
    NSLog(@"Called method: -(IBAction)nextCard:");

    NSString *questionString = [[questionView textStorage] string];
    NSString *answerString = [[answerView textStorage] string];

    /* Make sure we get input in both fields, otherwise do nothing */
    /* Todo: use a regexp lib to make this more robust */
    NSString *questionWithoutWhitespace = [questionString stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
    NSString *answerWithoutWhitespace = [answerString stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];

    NSLog(@"   questionString: %@", questionString);
    NSLog(@"   answerString: %@", answerString);

    if ( ([questionWithoutWhitespace length] != 0) && ([answerWithoutWhitespace length] != 0) )
    {
        Flashcard *flashcard = [Flashcard newCardWithQuestion:questionString andAnswer:answerString];


        NSLog(@"   Flashcard->question: %@", [flashcard getQuestion]);
        NSLog(@"   Flashcard->answer: %@", [flashcard getAnswer]);


        [cardList addObject:flashcard];

        NSLog (@"   [cardList count]: %d", [cardList count]);   
        NSLog(@"     FlashCard %i, question: %@", i, [[cardList objectAtIndex:i] getQuestion]);
        NSLog(@"     FlashCard %i, answer: %@", i, [[cardList objectAtIndex:i] getAnswer]);
        i++;

        [self clearCard];
    }
}
```

Here is the output after I call it a few times:

```
[Session started at 2010-12-15 22:27:21 -0800.]
Called -(void)awakeFromNib
> Clicked "Next Card" button
Called method: -(IBAction)nextCard:
questionString: q1
answerString: a1
Flashcard->question: q1
Flashcard->answer: a1
[cardList count]: 1
FlashCard 0, question: q1
FlashCard 0, answer: a1
Called Method: -(void)clearCard

> Clicked "Next Card" button
Called method: -(IBAction)nextCard:
questionString: q2
answerString: a2
Flashcard->question: q2
Flashcard->answer: a2
[cardList count]: 2
FlashCard 0, question: q2
FlashCard 0, answer: a2
Called Method: -(void)clearCard


> Selected "File -> New" menu option
Called method: -(IBAction)newCardSet:
 cardList: 
 [cardList count]: 2
    Element 0 = <Flashcard: 0x480570>
      FlashCard 0, question: 
      FlashCard 0, answer: 
    Element 1 = <Flashcard: 0x473b70>
FlashCard 1, question: 
FlashCard 1, answer:
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in these two lines:

```
NSString *questionString = [[questionView textStorage] string];
NSString *answerString = [[answerView textStorage] string];
```

The `string` method comes from [NSAttributedString](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSAttributedString_Class/Reference/Reference.html%23//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSAttributedString).  The docs say this:

> For performance reasons, this method returns the current backing store of the attributed string object. If you want to maintain a snapshot of this as you manipulate the returned string, you should make a copy of the appropriate substring.

So you need to replace the two lines with:

```
NSString *questionString = [[[[questionView textStorage] string] copy] autorelease];
NSString *answerString = [[[[answerView textStorage] string] copy] autorelease];
```

This is because an NSTextStorage is ann NSMutableAttributedString and when that gets set to blank, the string you received gets emptied.

---

Unrelated but you might want to set `i` to `[cardList count]` at the beginning instead of `0`.

Also, methods beginning with `new` are expected to return an object you own according to the [memory management rules](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html).  If `newCardWithQuestion:andAnswer:` conforms to the rules, your code is leaking.  If not, you should rename the method, probably by dropping the word "new".

Answer (score 0):

My guess based solely on what you've shown here: the two strings are not being `retain`'d or `copy`'d when you create your `FlashCard` object here:

```
Flashcard *flashcard = [Flashcard newCardWithQuestion:questionString andAnswer:answerString];
```

What does that method look like? At some point in that method, if those two strings are instance variables, they should be retained or copied to your instance of `flashcard`.

---

Also, and this is unrelated to your issue, but when dealing with Cocoa, you tend to name your accessory methods `- (void)key`, instead of `- (void)getKey`, where `key` usually is your instance variable name.

Not only is this convention, but it also allows you to do really useful things with the Runtime, and if you use Declared properties, these methods are created for you. Check out Key-Value Coding if you'd like to know more. Really fantastic things are built on top of it.

Comment: Thanks!!!!   + (id)newCardWithQuestion:(NSString *)question andAnswer:(NSString *)answer 
{ 
    id newCard = [[self alloc] init];  
    [newCard setQuestion:question];
 [newCard setAnswer:answer]; 
    return [newCard autorelease]; 
}

Comment: Also, noob question (I'll RTFM stackoverflow soon, but how do you add returns to comment field?)

Comment: Success!                                                                     + (id)newCardWithQuestion:(NSString *)question andAnswer:(NSString *)answer 
{ 
    id newCard = [[self alloc] init];  
    [newCard setQuestion:[question copy]];
 [newCard setAnswer:[answer copy]]; 
    return [newCard autorelease]; 
}

Comment: This buys me time till I can master memory mgmt (believe it or not, I used to know a lot about Objective C).

Comment: @user Also, for memory management, your setter methods are typically responsible for object ownership. So instead of passing `[answer copy]`, the setter method itself should perform the copy on any incoming data. `copy` for strings, `retain` for most other object types. And you should really look into using Properties, as they take all of the hard work out of it.